# How do i make a download button that appears after 5 seconds with a countdown In Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

How do I make a download button that appears after 5 seconds with a countdown In Laravel
Hey Guys I Am Making Download Buttom Appearf 5 Second But Code Not Working,I have added a download function to my website. After 5 second, I started downloading the downloaded Butom automatically but the code is not working.

My Website- https://oyeimagens.com/foto/5/imagens-de-bom-dai-para-amor
CODE

```
 <div class="inner-downloadsection"> <div> <button aria-label="download" id="downloadBtn" class="downloadBtn btn btn-danger btn-block circle" style="border-radius: 20px;
    margin: .1em;
    font-size: .7em;
    font-weight: 300 !important;
    background: linear-gradient(50deg,#3981e6 1%,#488ef1 99%);"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down"></i> Download </button> </div> </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalDownload" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header"><button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
<p class="modal-titlem text-center"> Select Resolution &amp; Download </p>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
<center>
<div class="btn-group btn-block margin-bottom-10">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block dropdown-toggle margin-top-15" id="makingdifferenttimer" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-download myicon-right"></i> {{trans('misc.download')}} <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>

         <ul class="dropdown-menu arrowDownload dd-close btn-block">
            @foreach( $stockImages as $stock )
            <?php
            switch( $stock->type ) {
            case 'small':
                $_size          = trans('misc.s');
                break;
            case 'medium':
                $_size          = trans('misc.m');
                break;
            case 'large':
                $_size          = trans('misc.l');
                break;

        }
             ?>
                <li><a href="{{url('download',$stock->token)}}/{{$stock->type}}"><span class="label label-default myicon-right">{{$_size}}</span> {{$stock->resolution}} <span class="pull-right">{{$stock->size}}</span></a></li>
            @endforeach
          </ul>
        </div>
</center>
    </div>
<div id="countdowntimer"><b>Fetching file to Download... Wait<div id="countdown"><div id="countdown-number">4</div><svg><circle r="18" cx="20" cy="20"></circle></svg></div></b></div><b>
<div class="list-wrap">
<div>
</div>
</div>
</b></div><b>
</b></div>
    </div>  

                     Javascript
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
$('.downloadBtn').click(function () 
{
  var loimg = "https://oyeimagens.com/public/svg/loader.svg";

  $('#modalDownload').modal('toggle');window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
     
    if( $("#makingdifferenttimer").css('display') == 'none' )
  {
  
    $("#countdowntimer").show();
    clearTimeout(ctimer);
    var countdownNumberEl = document.getElementById('countdown-number');
    countdownNumberEl.textContent = countdown;
    ctimer = setInterval(function(){
      --countdown;
      if( countdown == 0 ){
        clearTimeout(ctimer);
        $("#countdowntimer").hide();
        $("#makingdifferenttimer").fadeIn(500);
      }else{
        countdownNumberEl.textContent = countdown;
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
  
});
```

Comment: Where does this have anything to do with PHP or Laravel? Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with only RENDERED HTML, Script and relevant CSS. Also post any error messages you have in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ctimer = setInterval(function(){})
```

Comment: Where  I Can Use This Code- ctimer = setInterval(function(){

Comment: https://codepen.io/mazbron/pen/aNEMRb